# need help regarding global variables on multiple pages with 1 js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my home page i have 2 input fields (`FromZip` and `ToZip`). Besides them is an `<a>` tag that calls the function `window.open`. These 2 inputs should share only 1 pop up page. This pop up page will allow the user to choose a state and city and the resulting zipcode will be posted on the home page. Here are some codes:

Front page (html):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/zipcodehelper/groupfunctions.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="RFromZip" id="RFromZip" placeholder="From Zip Code" ></input>                  
<a class="zipbutton" id="RFromZip" name="RFromZip" onclick="openpage()">?</a>                                       
<input type="text" name="RToZip" id="RToZip" placeholder="To Zip Code" ></input>                    
<a class="zipbutton" id="RToZip" name="RToZip" onclick="openpage2()">?</a>
```

js file:

```
var choice;
function openpage() {
    choice == "FromZip";
    window.open('http://cheapestmovingquote.com/zipcodehelper/ResidentialFromZip.php', 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=500,left=500,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
}

function openpage2() {
    choice == "ToZip";
    window.open('http://cheapestmovingquote.com/zipcodehelper/ResidentialFromZip.php', 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=500,left=500,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
}

function post_value() {
    if (choice == "FromZip") {
        alert(window.choice);
        window.opener.document.getElementById("RFromZip").value = document.getElementById("cityBox").value;
        self.close();
    }

    if (choice == "ToZip") {
        alert(window.choice);
        //window.opener.document.getElementById("RToZip").value = document.getElementById("cityBox").value;
        self.close();
    }

}
```

so what happen is: `home->user click the help button->select city->select state->dropdown generates zip->click submit->value of zip posted on home page`. But since the 2 `<a>` shares the same `window.open`, i don't know how to tell the script to post whether on `FromZip` or `ToZip`.

Comment: Is the same javascript file being loaded on both the base page and the front page? Are both the pages on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear about what you are asking, but this should help.

Assignment statements should use a single `=`

```
function openpage() {
    choice = "FromZip";
    window.open('http://cheapestmovingquote.com/zipcodehelper/ResidentialFromZip.php', 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=500,left=500,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
}

function openpage2() {
    choice = "ToZip";
    window.open('http://cheapestmovingquote.com/zipcodehelper/ResidentialFromZip.php', 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=500,left=500,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
}
```